# Load external web library on angular 4 typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to load my spotfire javascript API library :

I can't do that in my index.html because this url must be saved into my environment.ts file.

I have try to call this api with the code below :

```
System.import('https://spotfire-next.cloud.tibco.com/spotfire/wp/GetJavaScriptApi.ashx?Version=7.5').then(file => {
   // perform additional interactions after the resource has been asynchronously fetched
});
```

But there is an error "cannot lod module".

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting this link into the `scripts` array in the `angular.cli.json` file?

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Yes but in this file i can't load external ressources. I can't use environnement variable in my angular cli json file.